# Getting duplicates with BETWEEN query ruby on rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

When I attempt to retrieve records with a date range query using record_date >= 'start_date' AND record_date <= 'end_date'. I receive the same records back 3 times. I don't know why this is happening. I'm using ransack gem.

**Server log**

```
Facility load (1.9ms) SELECT "facilities".* FROM "facilities" LEFT OUTER JOIN "chart_records" ON "chart_records"."facility_id" = "facilities"."id" WHERE ("chart_records"."record_date" > = '2020-06-1' AND "chart_records"."record_date" <= '2020-06-04' AND facilities."name"= 'LVHH') ORDER BY "facilities"."id" ASC LIMIT $1 [["LIMIT", 1]]
```

**reports_controller.rb**

```
def chart_report_facility_detail

@d = Facility.ransack(params[:q])
@chart_records = @d.result.includes([:chart_records])

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html
 end
end
```

**view/index.html.erb**

```
<% @chart_records.each do |facility| %>
   <% facility.chart_records.between_dates(params[:date_1], params[:date_2]).order(record_date: :desc).distinct.each do |chart_record| %>
 <%= chart_record.attr %>
....
...
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

**response**: prints out the same record 3 times in a row

**How can I make it so that the BETWEEN query only returns each individual record once?**

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by adding **uniq** to the original ransack query statement.